# Can't find a "not equal" css attribute selector

Tags: css

I want to target div elements where the attribute "foo" has a value.

```
<div foo="x">XXX</div>
<div foo="">YYY</div>
```

I have tried this css, but it doesn't work:

```
[foo!='']
{
   background: red;
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

Answer (score 282, accepted):

Use the code like this:

```
div[foo]:not([foo=''])
{
    /* CSS Applied to divs having foo value Not nothing (or having a foo value assigned) */
}
```

Answer (score 35):

One problem with the accepted answer is that it will also select elements that do not have a `foo` attribute at all.  Consider:

```
<div>No foo</div>
<div foo="">Empty foo</div>
<div foo="x">XXX</div>
<div foo="y">YYY</div>
<div foo="z">ZZZ</div>
```

`div:not([foo=''])` will select both the first and second `div` elements.  If you only want `div` elements that have an attribute foo that is set to an empty string, you should use:

```
div[foo]:not([foo=''])
```

If you want all elements with attribute `foo` that is neither `y` nor `z`, you should use:

```
div[foo]:not([foo='y']):not([foo='z'])
```

Answer (score 20):

```
:not([foo=''])
{
    background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gsLvuys0/

Answer (score 5):

BTW if you are trying to select all elements with a certain attribute except for ones with the specific value, you could do something like this:

```css
[data-foo]:not([data-foo="foo"]) {
  /* matches <div data-foo="bar"> but not <div data-foo="foo"> or <div> */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the first one using

```
[foo = 'x']{
  background:red;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/n5xo0vtz/)

[Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: Suppose there are 100 divs out of which foo value is absent(foo='') for 50 divs and other 50 divs have different foo value say foo=x or y etc then you need to write 50 selectors if we follow above solution

Comment: That is not the op wants :"I want to target only the first of the following divs with a css attribute selector"

Comment: Your answer is right with his requirement but not a general solution which other people have given.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate You're correct. I want the more generic solution. I updated the question to reflect that.