# Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying convert below lines in javascript but getting below error

**Error**:
Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.usuggest li[aria-selected!='true']'
**Jquery code**

```
$(".usuggest li[aria-selected!='true']").eq(0).attr('aria-selected', 'true');
```

**javascript**

```
document.querySelectorAll(".usuggest li[aria-selected!='true']")[0].setAttribute('aria-selected', 'true')
```

Comment: Read the complete error message, and most importantly the part you've cut off before posting it here, and you will find the problem: `'.usuggest li[aria-selected!='true']' is not a valid selector`

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @mplungjan The selector is not invalid when used with jQuery, as mentioned in the dupe target or here: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Comment: @Andreas Wow. Never knew (and would never have used it either) : https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fn54u3gw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll mentions that the selector that you pass must be a valid CSS selector. In fact, if you look at the full error generated by your code, it gives the following:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.usuggest li[aria-selected!='true']' is not a valid selector.
```

Telling us that there is an issue with the selector.

Moving to the CSS selectors at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors and attribute selectors at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors, we see that to select an attribute, `!=` is not a valid operator. From [Can't find a "not equal" css attribute selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287229/cant-find-a-not-equal-css-attribute-selector) we can then see that we would need to prepend with `:not` to apply the inverse and then do an equality check.

This gives us the following updated JavaScript

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".usuggest li:not([aria-selected='true'])")
```

Which should do what you want.

This then makes the entire query:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".usuggest li:not([aria-selected='true'])")[0].setAttribute('aria-selected', 'true');
```

Since the `querySelectorAll` may not return results, I would recommend doing the following:

```js
const falseListItems = document.querySelectorAll(".usuggest li:not([aria-selected='true'])");

if (falseListItems.length > 0) {
    falseListItems[0].setAttribute('aria-selected', 'true');
}
```

If you can guarantee that the query will lead to a single result, then the extra if statement is not necessary of course.

Comment: I want to convert that jquery line to javascript

Comment: @user944513 Then do some research and read the answer or the dupe target.

Comment: @user944513 I believe the answer did this before and explained your issue, however I have updated it to make it clearer

Answer (score -2):

You can split the command into 2-3 lines, to debug easily,

`const element = document.querySelectorAll(".usuggest li[aria-selected!='true']");`

// you can check value 0f element here: `console.log(element);`

`element[0].setAttribute('aria-selected', 'true');`

If this too cause error, please reply with output of  `console.log(element);`